# Testing that function is called with parameter in a Promise

Tags: node.js, unit-testing, mocha.js, sinon

Given these 2 functions

```
function func1() {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    return resolve({
      method: function(variable) {
        return variable
      }
    })
  })
}

function func2() {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    func1()
    .then(obj => {
      return resolve(obj.method('stuff'))
    })
  })
}
```

*Note: They are each in a separate module, with `func2` require'ing/importing `func1`*

I'm wondering how I should go about asserting that `func2` resolves `obj.method()` with `stuff` as the argument. I was thinking about stubbing it using sinonJS, but I'm not sure how to go about stubbing it (As I can't really require/import the obj method to stub in my unit-test file).

My available test-suite is Mocha/Chai/Sinon, however if it's doable in some other way, those aren't a strict requirement.

Comment: Mocha's documentation has a whole section on how to test asynchronous functions -- http://mochajs.org/#asynchronous-code

Comment: That is true, but that is not the issue. My problem is how to go about testing/asserting that a method of an object, that only exists within an internal function of a module, is called with a specific argument. Normally I’d just stub, using sinonJS, the method with sinon.stub(obj, ‘method’) but I’m having a hard time seeing how that’s supposed to be done here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Slight workaround, but you should be able to do something like the following.

```
import * as functions from './func1';

const obj = {
  method: sinon.spy()
};

sinon.stub(functions, 'func1')
  .returns(new Promise(obj));

expect(obj.method).to.have.been.calledWith('stuff'); // sinon-chai expectation
```